# ASP.NET Core Web API : how to format my results correctly using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I am losing my mind trying to coerce data from Entity Framework Core and output the data using an ASP.NET Core Web API where the data will ultimately be consumed by a Blazor WASM app. The data store is a Postgresql database. My partner in crime is requesting the data be formatted specifically so that some child classes/objects are presented in summarized form(id/name) and others with full detail.

The first batch of code is my entity classes. Most of this is autogenerated database-first as I am working with an existing batch of Winforms apps and existing data:

```
//entity classes
public partial class Appuser
{
    public int Appuserid { get; set; }
    public string Familyname { get; set; }
    public string Givennames { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; } 
    public string? Hash { get; set; }
    public string? Salt { get; set; }
    public int? Oup { get; set; }
    public short Active { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
}

public partial class Part
{
    public int Partid { get; set; }
    public int Partclassid { get; set; }
    public string Partnumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public string? Uom { get; set; }
    public string? Customernumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? Width { get; set; }
    public decimal? Length { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
    public bool? Pstexempt { get; set; }
    public int? Sagecode { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }

    public virtual Partclass Partclass { get; set; }
    public virtual Sagecode? SagecodeNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Partclass
{
    public int Partclassid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class Purchaserequest
{
    public int Purchaserequestid { get; set; }
    public string Purchaserequestnumber { get; set; }
    public int? Vendorid { get; set; }
    public int? Enteredby { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datecreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Datesubmitted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dateclosed { get; set; }
    public int? Purchaserequeststatusid { get; set; }
    public string? Comments { get; set; }
    public string? Purpose { get; set; }
    public string? Authcomments { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Authactiondate { get; set; }
    public int? Authority { get; set; }
    public int? Urgencyid { get; set; }

    public virtual Appuser? AuthorityNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Appuser? EnteredbyNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Purchaserequeststatus? Purchaserequeststatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Urgency? Urgency { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor? Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Purchaserequestline> Purchaserequestlines { get; set; }
}

public partial class Purchaserequestline
{
    public int Purchaserequestlineid { get; set; }
    public int Purchaserequestid { get; set; }
    public int? Partid { get; set; }
    public string Uom { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Itemdescription { get; set; }
    public string? Comments { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string? Vendorpartno { get; set; }
    public string? Customerpartnumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? Qty { get; set; }
    public int? Sagecode { get; set; }

    public virtual Part? Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Sagecode? SagecodeNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Purchaserequeststatus
{
    public int Purchaserequeststatusid { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class Sagecode
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? Class { get; set; }
    public int? Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual Sagecodeclass? ClassNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Sagecode? ParentNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Sagecodeclass
{
    public int Classid { get; set; }
    public string Classname { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Sagecode> Sagecodes { get; set; }
}

public partial class Urgency
{
    public int Urgencyid { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Vendor
{
    public int Vendorid { get; set; }
    public string Vendorname { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? Address2 { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? Provincecd { get; set; }
    public string? Countrycd { get; set; }
    public string? Postalcode { get; set; }
    public string? Comments { get; set; }
    public short Active { get; set; }
    public short? Pstexempt { get; set; }
}
```

The following are my data transfer objects used to pass my data:

```
//DTO records

public record AppUserDTO
{
    public int Appuserid { get; init; }
    public string Familyname { get; init; }
    public string Givennames { get; init; }
    public string Login { get; init; }
    public int? Oup { get; init; }
    public short Active { get; init; }
    public string? Email { get; init; }
}

public record LookupDTO
{
    public int id { get; init; }
    public string name { get; init; }
}

public record PartDTO
{
    public int Partid { get; init; }
    public virtual Partclass Partclass { get; init; }
    public string Partnumber { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; init; }
    public int Qty { get; init; }
    public string? Uom { get; init; }
    public string? Customernumber { get; init; }
    public decimal? Width { get; init; }
    public decimal? Length { get; init; }
    public virtual Pricemethod? MaterialpricemethodNavigation { get; init; }
    public string? Comment { get; init; }
    public bool? Pstexempt { get; init; }
    public virtual Sagecode? SagecodeNavigation { get; init; }
    public bool? Active { get; init; }
}

public record PartclassDTO
{
    public int Partclassid { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string? Description { get; init; }
}

public record PreqDTO
{
    public int Purchaserequestid { get; init; }
    public string Purchaserequestnumber { get; init; } = null!;
    public virtual LookupDTO? Vendor { get; init; }
    public virtual LookupDTO? EnteredbyNavigation { get; init; }
    public DateTime Datecreated { get; init; }
    public DateTime? Datesubmitted { get; init; }
    public DateTime? Dateclosed { get; init; }
    public virtual LookupDTO? Purchaserequeststatus { get; init; }
    public string? Comments { get; init; }
    public string? Purpose { get; init; }
    public string? Authcomments { get; init; }
    public DateTime? Authactiondate { get; init; }
    public virtual LookupDTO? AuthorityNavigation { get; init; }
    public virtual LookupDTO? Urgency { get; init; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseRequestLineDTO> Purchaserequestlines { get; init; }
    public virtual ICollection<Purchaserequesturl> Purchaserequesturls { get; init; }
}

public record PurchaseRequestLineDTO
{
    public int Purchaserequestlineid { get; init; }
    public int Purchaserequestid { get; init; }
    public virtual LookupDTO? Part { get; init; }
    public string Uom { get; init; }
    public string? Itemdescription { get; init; }
    public string? Comments { get; init; }
    public decimal? Price { get; init; }
    public string? Vendorpartno { get; init; }
    public string? Customerpartnumber { get; init; }
    public decimal? Qty { get; init; }
    public virtual SagecodeDTO? SagecodeNavigation { get; set; }
}

public record PurchaseRequestStatusDTO
{
    public int Purchaserequeststatusid { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; init; }
}

public record SagecodeDTO
{
    public int Code { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; init; }
    public virtual Sagecodeclass? ClassNavigation { get; init; }
    public virtual Sagecode? ParentNavigation { get; init; }
}

public record SagecodeclassDTO
{
    public int Classid { get; init; }
    public string Classname { get; init; }
}

public record UrgencyDTO
{
    public int Urgencyid { get; init; } 
    public string? Name { get; init; }
}

public record VendorDTO
(
    public int Vendorid { get; init; }
    public string Vendorname { get; init; }
    public string? Address { get; init; }
    public string? Address2 { get; init; }
    public string? City { get; init; }
    public string? Provincecd { get; init; }
    public string? Countrycd { get; init; }
    public string? Postalcode { get; init; }
    public string? Comments { get; init; }
    public short Active { get; init; }
    public short? Pstexempt { get; init; }
);
```

A partial listing of my AutoMapper configuration follows:

```
//AutoMapper Profile

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {  
        CreateMap<Part, PartDTO>();
        CreateMap<Partclass, PartclassDTO>();
        CreateMap<Vendor, VendorDTO>();
        CreateMap<Sagecode, SagecodeDTO>();
        CreateMap<Sagecodeclass, SagecodeclassDTO>();
        CreateMap<Urgency, UrgencyDTO>();
        CreateMap<Purchaserequestline, PurchaseRequestLineDTO>();
        CreateMap<Purchaserequeststatus, PurchaseRequestStatuysDTO>();
   
        CreateMap<Appuser, AppUserDTO>();

        CreateMap<Purchaserequest, PreqDTO>();
        CreateMap<Appuser, LookupDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Appuserid))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Givennames + " " + src.Familyname));
        CreateMap<Purchaserequeststatus, LookupDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Purchaserequeststatusid))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description));
        CreateMap<Urgency, LookupDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Urgencyid))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
        CreateMap<Vendor, LookupDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Vendorid))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Vendorname));
        CreateMap<Part, LookupDTO>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Partid))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Partnumber + " - " + src.Description));
        CreateMap<Purchaserequestline, PurchaseRequestLineDTO>();
        CreateMap<Purchaserequesturl, PurchaseRequestURLDTO>();
    }
}
```

My partner in crime wants the data for a single purchase request pulled from the `PurchaserequestController` returning a fairly complete object graph. I am providing this data from my `PurchaserequestRepository` using:

```
//the repository does the magic to pull the data required
public async Task<Purchaserequest> GetPurchaseRequestById(int id, bool trackChanges)
{
    return await FindByCondition(p => p.Purchaserequestid.Equals(id), trackChanges)
        .Include(p => p.Purchaserequestlines)
            .ThenInclude(l=> l.SagecodeNavigation)
        .Include(p => p.Purchaserequesturls)
        .Include(p => p.Vendor)
        .Include(p => p.Purchaserequeststatus)
        .Include(p => p.Urgency)
        .Include(p => p.AuthorityNavigation)
        .Include(p => p.EnteredbyNavigation)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

This is called from the `PurchaserequestService`:

```
//The controller uses the following Service call
//  my service pulls the entity graph from the repository
//  and formats it using the AutoMapper before returning to the caller as json
public async Task<PreqDTO> GetPurchaseRequestByIdAsync(int id, bool trackChanges)
{
    try
    {
        var preq = await _repository.PurchaseRequests.GetPurchaseRequestById(id, trackChanges);

        var dto = _mapper.Map<Purchaserequest, PreqDTO>(preq);

        return dto;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Something went wrong in the {nameof(GetPurchaseRequestByIdAsync)} service method {ex}");

        throw;
    }
}
```

The problem with all of this is that it feels like I am spinning my tires furiously for little benefit. I feel I am going to run into a lot of future issues with the AutoMapper mappings with multiple destination mappings for some source entities.

Am I doing this all wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Any ideas are much appreciated.

Sorry for the length of this post ... I am sure many will get tired of scrolling and run away.

Comment: You need `ProjectTo`, not `Map`. https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Thank you Lucian for your input.  It appears that may work.  I did find another way to do the same(similar) thing using ForPath in my mapping which seems to work ... maybe in spite of my efforts.